# Counting items with multiple criteria

Tags: powerpivot

I have a table (`getECRs`) in PowerPivot.

Right now, I've been able to create a calculated column that counts how many times the row's customer ID (BAN) occurs in the `BAN` column with the following formula:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(getECRs),ALLEXCEPT(getECRs,getECRs[BAN]))
```

What I'm having difficulty with is adding multiple criteria to the `CALCULATE` formula in PowerPivot.

Each row has a column that gives the date the request was generated `_CreateDateKey`. I'm trying to include criteria that would only include multiple BANs if they fall within 7 days (before or after) the `_CreateDateKey` for the row.

For example for one BAN, there are the following dates and their expected counts:

```
_CreateDateKey    Count    Explanation
6/13/2014         3        Does not include 6/23
6/13/2014         3        Does not include 6/23
6/16/2014         4        Includes all
6/23/2014         2        Does not include the 2 items from 6/13
```

In Excel I would use a `COUNTIFS` statement, like below to get the desired result (using table structure naming)

```
=COUNTIFS([BAN],[@BAN],[_CreateDateKey],">="&[@[_CreateDateKey]]-7,[_CreateDateKey],"<="&[@[_CreateDateKey]]+7)
```

But I can't seem to figure out the relative criteria needed for the dates. I tried the following as a criteria to the `CALCULATE` function, but it resulted in an error:

```
getECRs[_CreateDateKey]>=[_CreateDateKey]-7
```

Error: `Column '_CreateDateKey' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula answers your specific question. It's a good pattern to get down as it's highly re-usable - the EARLIER() is referencing the value of the current row (slightly more complex than this but that is the end result):

```
=
    CALCULATE (
       COUNTROWS ( getECRs ),
           FILTER (
             getECRs,
             getECRs[BAN] = EARLIER ( getECRs[BAN] )
             && getECRs[_CreateDateKey]
                 >= EARLIER ( getECRs[_CreateDateKey] ) - 7
             && getECRs[_CreateDateKey]
                 <= EARLIER ( getECRs[_CreateDateKey] ) + 7
                   )
               )
```

Fundamentally you should probably be looking to get away from the 'Excel mindset' of using a calculated column and deal with this using a measure.

An adaptation of the above would look like this - it would use the filter context of the PIVOT in which you were using it (e.g. if BAN was rows then you would get the count for that BAN).

You may need to adjust the ALL() if is too 'open' for your real world context and you might have to deal with totals using HASONEVALUE():

```
=
     CALCULATE (
          COUNTROWS ( getECRs ),
          FILTER (
            ALL(getECRs),
                getECRs[_CreateDateKey] >= MAX ( getECRs[_CreateDateKey] ) - 7 &&
                getECRs[_CreateDateKey] <= MAX ( getECRs[_CreateDateKey] ) + 7
                 )
                )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The data won't always be sorted (although I could adjust my query so it is). But even so, this doesn't take into consideration the 7 days before or after the current row's date.

Comment: I also completely agree about getting away from the "Excel Mindset." The result of this fuction will be used within an IF statement to return text so that I can use it as a Row or Column Label in my Pivot table. I was under the impression measures can't return text.

Comment: The sorting is irrelevant. The 7 day window should be trivial, I will edit my answer later. You absolutely can return text in a measure.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've got a lot to learn when it comes to PowerPivot. Your first function (for the calculated column) did the trick. The Measure you suggested isn't reporting as expected (text or not). Thanks for the help. It gets me moving.